# How to place company address and phone on each page of Liferay site?

Tags: java, jsp, layout, liferay, portlet

What is expected way to place company address on each page of the site? In page footer, for example?

Should I create custom layout, theme or only portlets can know this data?

How to know this data from layout or theme?

Is this true that, from within portlet class an organization addresses can be accessed by calling Organization class method, while organization phones can be accessing only by service call?

Answer (score 3):

Quick answer: You most likely have a custom theme. portal_normal.vm is the file that creates the basic page and by default also contains a footer. You can just enter it there. Hardcoding is easy (just put it in there, it's your theme anyway). If you want to access it from the database (e.g. an organization's phone number through the organization API), you can also do it by accessing the current organization through Liferay's API. Look up serviceLocator for this task, but be aware that any embedded code on this level must execute as quickly as possible as it otherwise might slow down your whole portal (it's executed on each single request).

You can also embed portlets (e.g. Web Content Display) in your theme. This is well documented in Liferay's documentation and easy to find. This gives you the opportunity to dynamically update the content at runtime.

Sorry, I'll have to let you google for the links yourself - just answering this in between two tasks

Comment: Sorry, but what is the most correct way? Placing credentials in the footer looks very common operation. How Liferay creators expected it will be done? Hardcoding is not applicable of course. And also I can't be responsible if Liferay API works slow. If accessing organization credentials via Liferay API is slow then it is also not correct way. So, embedded portlets are the answer? Will they work faster than embedded API calls?

Comment: May be I can place data in some common place (like session or something) with one single call and then access it fast from everywhere?

Comment: There's no single correct recommendation. Some discussion to be found here: https://www.liferay.com/de/web/raymond.auge/blog/-/blogs/embedding-portlets-in-themes-on-liferay